# Evaluate: $ \sum_{i}^{n+1} n !$

Tags: summation

$ \sum_{i}^{n+1} n !$

This sum is suppose to equal $(n+1)!$.  For some reason I don't get why.  Can anyone explain?

Taken directly from http://www.inchmeal.io/2016/01/15/how-to-prove-it-ch-7-sec-1.html q22(a) last part.

Comment: Did you mean $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}n!$?

Comment: If you mean $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}n!$ then $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}n!=n!\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}1$ so...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** All the terms are the same; $n!$ does not depend on $i$.

Comment: So n! added n+1 times?  That's what we are doing?

Comment: @helios123 Yes, that's exactly what the sum is. Do you see why it simplifies to $(n+1)!$ now?

Comment: (That is, of course, assuming the starting index for $i$ is $1$.)

Answer (score 0):

Example: $\sum_{1}^{5}2 = 5 \times 2 = 10$; $\sum_{1}^{n}x = n \times x = nx$ for all integers $n \geq 1$ and all real $x$.

Clearly, we have 
$$
\sum_{1}^{n+1}n! = (n+1)\times n! = (n+1)!.
$$